# Irreducible factors of the A-polynomial

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

The A-polynomial $A_K$ of a knot $K$ describes the  irreducible "non-abelian" components of the $SL(2)$-character variety of $S^3-K.$
Does anyone know a knot K for which $A_K$ has more irreducible factors than the number of the above non-abelian components?

Alternative formulation: We say that $A(l,m)$ is "invariant" if $A(m^{-1},l^{-1})$ equals $A(l,m)$ mutiplied by a monomial in $m$ and $l$. By its construction, $A_K$ is invariant.
Is there known $K$ for which $A_K$ has an irreducible factor which is not invariant?

Comment: I do not think your description of the A-polynomial is quite accurate and, accordingly, I do not really understand the question. To define the A-polynomial one looks at the projection of the character variety of the knot exterior to the "eigenvalue variety" (by restricting representations to the fundamental group of the boundary torus). Then one considers the union of curve components of this projection and takes $A_K$ to be a generator of the defining ideal of this union. Note that there could be, a priori, isolated points in the above projection. These do not count.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I didn't include a super precise definition of the A-polynomial (Assume the standard one). But I don't see anything wrong with my question.

Comment: To elaborate: for my question, you can assume that there are no islated points in the projection you mention (especially that no example is known).

Comment: I still do not understand your question, but it might be just me.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think the point of the question is that there could be an A-polynomial whose factors are not invariant under (L,M) -> (1/L,1/M). For example, (L+LM+ M^2)(1/L+1/(LM)+1/M^2) is invariant under this substitution but the factors are not (up to multiplying by powers of L, M).